# Cannot find name 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a node.js project. Moved some code from an other Next.js / React /Typescript project. Got this error:

```
/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Tikex/typescript-starter/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts:477:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.
```

`CanvasRenderingContext2D` is not found, though it is in `node_modules`, in

`/node_modules/typescript/lib/li.dom.d.ts`.

What is the problem?

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

index.ts is quite long, but thi is the start of the method:

```js
const getLines = (
  context: CanvasRenderingContext2D | SKRSContext2D,
  text: string,
  textFont: string,
  maxTextWidth: number
) => {
```

Comment: please, provide index.ts?

Comment: Show your tsconfig.json

Comment: filled in tsonfig.json

Comment: Node.js has no DOM, thus no CanvasRenderingContext2D
If you want to utilise canvas on Node.js, use the package "node-canvas" which has the type "CanvasRenderingContext2D"